# Load Image and external text in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, list, text, actionscript, external

Working on a project, and this is what I currently got. I got a List component with items in it, and currently when you click on it, it will load a image on the UIloader. What else I need is to be able to load information about that image in a textbox under it. Below is the current actionscript I have, but not able to get the external text file to load.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

loadlist.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, loadFile);
function loadFile(e:Event):void {
    loadWindow.source = e.target.selectedItem.data;
}


loadlist.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, showText);

function showText(event:Event):void{
    info.load(new URLRequest("text\picture1.txt"));
}
```

Edit: Here is a screen shot of what I got going on!
http://i59.tinypic.com/23u8ljt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to load an image (if not, just let me know and I'll create an example as well) and just want to load a text file, you can use something like:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
// remember to have a text file with the same name (or rename as you prefer)
loader.load(new URLRequest('myText.txt'));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);

function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace(loader.data);
}
```

But analyzing your question, if you want to load image and information about that image (guessing that you are not only talking about [Metadata](https://code.google.com/p/as3-xmp-file/)), I suggest you to use XML or JSON, so, you can organize all images and it's information, and also it will be easy to maintain.

```
var myXML:XML;

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);
myLoader.load(new URLRequest('myXMLFile.xml'));

function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    myXML = new XML(event.target.data);
    for (var i:int = 0, numXMLChildren:uint = myXML.children().length(); i < numXMLChildren; i++)
    {
        // using myXML.image[i] to get the URL and load the image
        trace("My image number is " + (i+1) + ", it's title is " + myXML.image[i].@title + " and it's URL is " + myXML.image[i]);
    };
}
```

I created a 'dummy' XML just to illustrate and provide you some idea, but, you are free to include more details based on your needs.

```
//myXMLFile.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<imageGallery>
    <image title="image 1...">image1.jpg</image>
    <image title="image 2...">image2.jpg</image>
    <image title="image 3...">image3.jpg</image>
</imageGallery>
```

Use these examples to understand some approaches and define what is the best for your case, they are not optimized, not well elaborated or planned, so, I do recommend you to use the concept and improve.

Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I got 2 list components, each one when I click an item in the list, it will load my image on the right and the textbox below it....Thanks for your help